# Solution set in form of an equation

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

Given, $f(x,y) = \dfrac{x}{y}-\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)}$ and $g(x) = x$. What is the solution of $f(x,y) = g(x)$?

The intuitive way of solving the equation was to just plug in $x$ in place of $y$ in $f$ so any value of $x$ would give satisfy the equation with $f \in \mathbb{R}$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f \in \mathbb{C}$ for $x < 0$.

But that's not the kind of solution I wanted. Is there some way which could lead to:

$$\Re(f(x,y)-g(x)) - x = y - x$$

..or

$$\Re(f(x,y)-g(x)) - y = x - y$$

I tried doing,

$$\dfrac{x}{y}-x-\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)} = 0$$
$$\dfrac{x-xy}{y}-\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)} = 0$$
$$(y^{x})^{(1-y)}=x^y$$

I have no idea where to go next, is there any way that I could get that sole satisfying form or something similar to that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the equation 
$$\ln(y)\left(\frac{1-y}{y}\right)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

Comment: So then, $$\dfrac{\ln(|y|)}{y} - \ln(|y|) + \dfrac{i\pi}{y} - i\pi = \dfrac{\ln(|x|)}{x} + \dfrac{i\pi}{x}$$ due to which $$\Re(f-g) = \dfrac{\ln(|y|)}{y} - \ln(|y|) - \dfrac{\ln(|x|)}{x}$$ and as $y = x$, after some cancellation, $$\Re(f-g) = -\ln(|y|)$$. Which is sad.